# How to define a custom argument matcher with mockito in spec2?

Tags: scala, mockito, spec2

I want to verify if the business logic passes the expected `user` object to dao, but I can't figure how to write an custom argument matcher for it.

```
"user" should {
    "be saved" in {
        val dao = new UserDao()
        dao.save(any[User]) returns mock[User]

        runMyBusinessLogic();

        val expectedUser = new User("Freewind", 123.23234)
        there was one(dao).save(mymatcher(expectedUser));
    }
 }
```

The `User` class:

```
case class User(name:String, random: Double)
```

Which contains a `double` field, that I need to do some special comparison for it.

The `mymatcher` is the matcher I want to define:

```
def mymatcher(expected: User) = ??? {
    // compare `name` and `random`
}
```

But I don't know how to do it in `spec2`, and can't find any useful documents. Any helps?

Answer (score 4):

I use beLike matcher. Like this:

```
one(daoMock).insert { beLike[MyEntity] { case t:Entity => {
  t.summary mustEqual "Summary"
  t.description mustEqual "Description"
}}}
```

Inside beLike matcher you could use ordinary value matchers.

Comment: What are the required imports for the `beLike` matcher?

Comment: @Zoltán For the time I asked it was in trait "Specification" inherited from one of the "*Matchers" trait. (specs2 2.3.12)

Answer (score 2):

For mockito matching I used `Matchers.argThat`

```
import org.mockito.Matchers
import org.mockito.Mockito.verify

verify(service).methodCall(Matchers.argThat({
  case CaseClass("const", arg2) =>
    arg2 == expected
  case _ => false
}))
```