# Using any or anyNamed matchers for nested values with Mockito

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito

I'm trying to pass Mockito's argument matchers into nested objects values. I've successfully used something like this so far:

```
when(object.getData(any, any, userId: anyNamed("userId"))).thenAnswer((_) async => response);
```

However now I need to use `any` or `anyNamed` for nested values. The following code:

```
when(adapterMock.fetch(
  RequestOptions(
    method: anyNamed("method"),
    path: "orders",
  ),
  any,
  any,
)).thenAnswer((_) async =>response);
```

Gives an error:

```
Invalid argument(s): An ArgumentMatcher was declared as named method, but was not passed as an
argument named method.

BAD:  when(obj.fn(anyNamed: "a")))
GOOD: when(obj.fn(a: anyNamed: "a")))
```

Is there any correct way to provide nested arguments matchers?

Comment: You can use Matchers.argThat see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58500045/2695582

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that using nested matchers is [not possible](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/issues/280) in mockito. I ended up restructuring my project a little bit so I don't need to use such matchers anymore.

Answer (score 0):

use   `headers:captureAnyNamed("headers")`,